# Angular 4 - ngModelChange throw cannot read property '...' of undefined during two select form binding

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, undefined, angular-ngmodelchange

I have the following json model and want to have two select form (dropdown) in which the first dropdown will contain the **title** while the second dropdown contain the **authors** with the value depending on the which **title** to pick (first title has two, second has three).

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "bookA",
        "authors": [
            "authorA",
            "authorB"
        ]
},
 {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "bookB",
        "authors": [
            "authorA",
            "authorB",
            "authorC"
        ]
},
```

I am fairly new to Angular 4, but after searching around I come up with the following code in my html:

```
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="bookTitleField" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Title</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <select [(ngModel)]="currentInput.book.id" name="bookTitle" 
                (ngModelChange)="selectedBook=$event.target.value">
                    <option *ngFor="let b of books | async" value="{{b.id}}">{{b.title}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <label for="bookAuthorField" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Author/label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <select [(ngModel)]="currentInput.book.authors" *ngIf="currentInput.book.id" name="author">
                    <option *ngFor="let a of selectedBook" value="{{a.authors}}">{{a.authors}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The first dropdown works as intented, however when the second one is clicked, an error was thrown:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Which part of the code is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `target` that is `undefined` in your template. You would want to use `$event.id` to get the id value from the first dropdown. Also you want to use `[ngValue]` to bind the whole object in the first dropdown, so that you can show the authors in your next dropdown. So modify your code to something like this:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="chosenBook" name="bookTitle" (ngModelChange)="selectedBook.id = $event.id">
   <option *ngFor="let b of books | async" [ngValue]="b">{{b.title}}</option>
</select>

<label>Author</label>
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedBook.author">
  <option *ngFor="let a of chosenBook.authors">{{a}}</option>
</select>
```

Also remember to initialize your `selectedBook` and `chosenBook` so that you don't get an `undefined` error.

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tmapab?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: This is a step to right direction. However can I pass the ngValue in a parameter?

Comment: parameter? What do you mean?

Comment: Usually in regular textfield I use this `<input type="text" id="aField" name="aField" value="passMe" #textFieldA>` and to pass it I can just do `newMethod(textFieldA.value)` but this does not work with `ngValue`. Is there any way?

Comment: Why would you need that? What are you trying to achieve? You have your ngModelChange if you need to do something with your ngModel variable, no need for using parameters. This is why Angular is great, you have two-way-binding ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work but it is hard to say right now.
Other way is to use a function as show below,

```
<div *ngIf="books">              //added this condition
        <select [(ngModel)]="currentInput.book.id" name="bookTitle" 
                (ngModelChange)="setValue($event)">
</div>
setValue(model){
  this.selectedBook=model.target.value;
}
```